# Find a group such that $x^2 = x$ for all $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a group $G$ satisfying that $x^2 = x$ for all $x\in G$. I have to find the group. I was thinking that since I am asked to find the group it was probably the trivial group.

My thinking is that since $x^2 = x$ for all $x$, then $x^2x^{-1} = xx^{-1} = 1$. So $x = 1$. So the group is the trivial group. Is that right?

This is homework, so **if I am wrong**, then please just give me a hint.

Comment: $4$? Do you mean the group identity? If so, then this is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by 4?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant $1$.

Comment: @JohnDoe now, as MPW said, this is correct.

Comment: @graydad $1 + 1 = 0$, so the condition $x^2 = x$ does not hold.

Comment: @graydad: This is not a counterexample, since the group operation is addition, and your group does not satisfy the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct.

Let $x$ be any element in $G$. $$\begin{align} x^2 = x& \iff x^2x^{-1} = xx^{-1} \\&\iff (xx)x^{-1} = e \\  &\iff= x(xx^{-1})= e \\  &\iff  x = e\end{align}$$ where $e$ is the identity of the group.

So indeed, since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, $G$ must be the trivial group.

Comment: He/she already got that argument, and he/she said it was homework and just needed to know if she/he got the right argument and a hint if not. +0

Comment: What's the point of copying what the OP already said? This adds nothing to the post.